# What is the source of a quotation by Niels Bohr?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quote, physicists, bohr

[The quote](https://www.azquotes.com/quote/573998) is:

> When asked ... [about] an underlying quantum world, Bohr would answer,
> 'There is no quantum world. There is only an abstract quantum physical
> description. It is wrong to think that the task of physics is to find
> out how nature is. Physics concerns what we can say about Nature.'

What is the source of this quote?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source is Aage Petersen's article [*The Philosophy of Niels Bohr*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=DgcAAAAAMBAJ&lpg=PA36&pg=PA8&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), published in 1963. According to [N. David Mermin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N._David_Mermin), in his article [*What's Wrong with this Quantum World*](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1688051), “Bohr, who took writing very seriously indeed, never published such an assertion in any of his writings, although he repeatedly refined, reformulated and often simply repeated his position on the philosophical foundations of the quantum theory”.